# Check string with negative decimal values contains special characters

Tags: windows-10, string-manipulation

I need to check if a string with negative values contains special characters. When I type -7.!, -7.@, -7.# the special characters are found, the error message is sent and the program is closed, but when I type a valid value eg. -7.1, -7.5 the error message is sent and the program is also closed.

I tried a command that I found in the link:
[check-string-contains-special-characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58010150/check-string-contains-special-characters-in-batch-skript)

I tried this:

```
set /p "_vLUF=Valor LUFS: "
echo;!_vLUF!|findstr /r "[%% # & ^ @ $ ~ !]" >nul && echo Invalid Value goto exit
```

how to use this same findstr command to check the string, thus avoiding the use of several IF's, in the following rules.

Note: not in a single findstr, but using findstr commands.

The string can only contain:

```
- negative values;
- have more than 3 digits;
- numeric characters;
- only 1 decimal value (eg. -9.00, -7.01 are not allowed);
- numbers starting without 0 (eg. -010.0, -09.0 are not allowed);
- be between the values -9.0 to -0.0. (eg. -9.1 and 0.1 are not allowed)
```

Comment: According to the answer you quoted you should be using `findstr /L`

Comment: @DavidPostill worked too. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed your code:

```
set /p "_vLUF=Valor LUFS: "
echo %_vLUF%|findstr /r "[%#&^@$~!]" >nul && echo Invalid Value
```

Comment: worked, but there's a detail: when I type `-7.-` it considers it to be valid!... how do I disallow this value too?

Comment: I added `-` to the separators string.

Comment: now doesn't allow putting in valid values, eg. -7.1, -7.5... I think I'll have to split the string into integer part and decimal part for this to work. I'll do that and test it before accepted, ok?

Comment: Yes, findstr wildcard expressions are pretty limited. It will be hard to allow `-` only as first character in this same expression, so two findstr commands are required. Splitting into integer/decimal won't find `7-0`. To find `-` that is not in the first character position, use `findstr "..*-"` which finds it after at least one character.

Comment: OK... so how to do, using only findstr commands, to check this string under the following conditions: 1. it has to be ```only negative values```; 2. the values will be from ```-9.0 to -0.0``` (the sign "-" can only be in the first digit); 3. can only be ```numeric```; 4. can only have ```only 1 decimal point (-9.00... -0.00 cannot be accepted)```; 5. cannot contain ```any special characters```. If any of these conditions are true, the value is invalid.

Comment: This is very different from your initial question. Edit your post with several examples of string that obey these rules.

Comment: I put this information in my question as you instructed.

Comment: This is too complicated for findstr. I suggest using some other utility that can do real regex.

Comment: OK... but it's not a single findstr, it would be "using" the findstr commands.

Comment: I created multiple findstr commands and in one of them I also used your command that worked. Your tips helped a lot too, so I'm upvoting your answer. Thanks!